# Smart pointer destructors under exceptional circumstances

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

In reading up on smart pointers in C++, most of the information comes with a caveat :

> "Be warned that a smart pointer destructor will (may) not be called in
>   circumstances like an abnormal exit (by calling std::abort or
>   std::exit()), or when an exception propagates out of a thread's
>   primary function or when a method declared noexcept throws an
>   exception".

My question is that in all these cases, the program terminates eventually in which case the memory the smart pointer was pointing to is claimed back by the OS when the page tables for the process are cleared (I know that the C++ standard doesnt discuss page tables and virtual memory but I am mentioning it here because this is the standard practice in majority of the OSes out there).

So why is this warning issued? What is the worst thing that can happen if the destructor is not called? Or is this a warning that I need to be aware of when I use a smart pointer to manage a resource other than memory? If yes, then what are such resources?

Comment: The destructor of the pointed to object might sync and close external resources like a serial line, a file, a socket or maybe even set some GPIOs. So for the smart pointer it is mainly about freeing memory, but for the object that it holds more might be relevant.

Comment: Devise a destructor that has partial file data committed, the remainder sitting in a queue, and pull the plug. Your guess is as good as mine what eventually made it into the file. Send data over a socket, then terminate the connection mid-stream. The list of things that can be affected are limitless, left only to the imagination. And fwiw, the same problems can happen *without* smart pointers, especially with `std::abort`. So the only thing I see odd about that warning is its affinity to smart pointers.

Comment: So when I am using a smart pointer to manage these, then there is no guarantee that these will be closed. So what should a programmer do because the circumstances that I mentioned above will cause the program to terminate anyway and it has already gone beyond your control.

Comment: @AshishDaggubatti, you cannot do anything when a program/thread is terminated like that. The standard just sets the expectations of the program correctly.

Comment: @AshishDaggubatti You ask what a programmer can do? Prevent the mentioned circumstances to happen. Catch exceptions in `main`. Don't throw in functions that are declared `noexcept`. And don't call `abort` or `exit`, let all called functions return and in `main` just do a `return`.

Comment: @WernerHenze Lol. That was pretty obvious. I was just wondering if the reason for this caveat is that there is something else that the programmer should do. But looks like it is just mitigating those same circumstances which is the solution. Thanks Werner, WhozCraig and R Sahu

Comment: @AshishDaggubatti I might not have been clear enough: these circumstances are extraordinary circumstances that normally should not happen. The solution is to prevent them from happening as far as possible.

Comment: @AshishDaggubatti These caveats also apply to actions in destructors of automatic storage duration ("stack") objects. You can't **programatically** fix your program terminating abruptly, because *by definition* no more code runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already said in my comments the situations that the standard is talking about are exceptional circumstances that should not happen. Chances are very high that if they happen your program will not function properly anymore. So it is terminated and the standard does not guarantee that all destructors are called properly.

The solution is to prevent the circumstances to happening.

> abnormal exit (by calling std::abort or std::exit())

Don't call `abort` or `exit`. Let all called functions return and let `main` do a `return`.

> or when an exception propagates out of a thread's primary function

Catch all exceptions in `main`. Then `return`. Or if there are no global objects you can also `abort`.

> or when a method declared noexcept throws an exception".

Don't throw in `noexcept` functions.

The problems that can arise are not only memory related. A smart pointer that is deleting the pointer it holds triggers the destructor of the object that it points to. The object might hold external resources. These could be for example a file (or socket) that shall be flushed (writing out buffered I/O) before it is closed. It could also be something low level hardware related like a GPIO that for example turns a light on during an operation and turns it off in the destructor.